# for opera mini detect if mobile view is on or off using javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, view, opera

I want to show instruction to user of Opera Mini to turn mobile view setting off if the mobile view setting is on. For that I need to detect if it is ON

How can I do it using javascript

Comment: You can probably do it by placing some element that will have one size/position in regular view, and another size/position in mobile view. Then just check the size/position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have a JavaScript solution for you entirely, but here's a (albeit weak) css solution: Opera Mini uses screen media type by default and handheld media type if the user has explicitly switched to mobile view, so you could detect Opera Mini after pageload via JavaScript and then insert a message that is not visible if mobile view setting is off and vice versa.

```
var operaminimobileviewmessage = document.createElement("p");

operaminimobileviewmessage.id = 'ommvm';

operaminimobileviewmessage.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Turn Mobile View Off")); 

if(Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]"){

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(operaminimobileviewmessage);

  return false;
}
```

then in the your stylesheets define the element:

```
<style media="screen,projection">
p#ommvm{display:none}
</style>

<style media="handheld">
p#ommvm{display:block}
</style>
```